# My input element is not updating or display value manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have data coming from the backend that contains a table with the element `input` and I append this table to the body of my table.

So my problem input element is not updated a value even if I press inspect and set the value manually also is not display the value. I don't know what is going on.

This my code coming from backend (PHP):

```
public function get_target_type_record(Request $request){
  //...
  foreach ($routes as $list) {
    $table .= "<tr class='collapse order" . $i . " business_type_id_" . $item->id . "'>";
    $table .= "<td><i class=\"fa fa-minus-square\"></i> </td>";
    $table .= "<td>--</td>";
    $table .= " <td>" . $list->id . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td>" . $list->route_name . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td>
    <input type='text' class='form-control dynamic-input'
    value='0'>
    </td>";
    $table .= "<td></td></tr>";
  }

  return response()->json($table);
}
```

blade file (html):

```
<table class="table table-hover users-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="target-table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this my jQuery code:

```
$('#select2-target_type_group_menu2').on('change', function(event) {
  var menu2_id = this.value;
  var menu1_id = document.getElementById('menu1_id').value;
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{route('get_target_type_record')}}",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
      item_type : [
        menu1_id,
        menu2_id
      ],
    },
    success: function (data) {
      document.getElementById('item_IDs').value = data.item_IDs;

      $("#target-table").empty();
      $('#target-table').append(data.table);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Move this line to after append `document.getElementById('item_IDs').value = data.item_IDs;` .. Also **id must be unique** so don't use same id for more than one element .. Also I don't think `data.item_IDs` will return the desired result .. so `console.log(data);` first to check if there is any `data.itemIDs` or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure your ajax call returns data properly. Then the issue may be the jQuery part. Since you didn't allocate the property `table` for the $table variable when converting to JSON, you should use the ajax returned data like:

```
success: function (data) {
  document.getElementById('item_IDs').value = data.item_IDs;

  $("#target-table").empty();
  $('#target-table').append(data); //!!!
}
```

If you want keep the property,try:

```
return response()->json(['table'=>$table]);
```

Comment: thanks @Phil for your quick response, but did not work

Comment: I have verified in my local environment. It should work. You could check your backend code add `dd` it.

Comment: this is my return data from backend
`"<tr data-toggle='collapse' class='item_id_8' data-target='.order60163c0d27880'><td><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i></td><td>8</td><td>8 | Eat</td><td>Eat</td></tr><tr class='collapse order60163c0d27880 business_type_id_8'><td><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> </td><td>--</td> <td>23</td><td>MUBEEN</td><td>4050</td><td></td></tr><tr class='collapse order60163c0d27880 business_type_id_8'><td><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> </td><td>--</td>  etc..`

its more data, just I showed to you to confirm for you data is comming

Comment: it worked. thanks, Phil
the problem is my ids are duplicated